# Cannot set property 'src' of null at setTimeout

Tags: javascript

This is part of a card game, where when two out of 6 cards are flipped and are a match, I need to replace them with "clear.png" so they look like they disappeared. If they don't match, I want to replace them with the img "back.png" after 1.5 seconds. Only two cards will be flipped at any one time.

I tried using getElementsByTagName" instead of getElementsById when I try to access "src" through flipped, this time, the error did not come up but it does not do anything (setTimeout does not time out).

I looked at the other questions related to this, but nothing suggested in those posts seems to be working. Thanks for the help. 
Here is my HTML and part of the .js below it:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title><style> 
            img {margin: 10px;}
        </style>
        <script src="matching.js" defer></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="matchingcards"></div>
            <input id="restart" type="submit" value="Restart Game">

        </body>
        </html>

    <script>
    ......
    var flipped = [];
    function flipcards(card, value) {
    if(card.getAttribute("src") == "back.png" && flipped.length < 2){
        console.log(card.getAttribute("src"))
        console.log("get attribute back.png")
        card.src = value;

        if(flipped.length == 0){ flipped.push(value); } 
        else if(flipped.length == 1) {
            flipped.push(value);
            if(flipped[0].charAt(0) == flipped[1].charAt(0)) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    document.getElementById(flipped[0]).src = "clear.png";
                    document.getElementById(flipped[1]).src = "clear.png";
                    flipped = [];
                }, 1500);
            } else {
                if(flipped.length == 2){
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        document.getElementById(flipped[0]).src = "back.png";
                        document.getElementById(flipped[1]).src = "back.png";
                        flipped = [];
                    }, 1500);
                }
            }
        }
    }
} 
</script>
```

Comment: What is ``value``? Is there ``<img>`` tags with the ``id`` attribute set to the value of ``value``?

Comment: can you post the relevant part of your markup? I think part of your problem is in the way you're using `getElementById` -- check out its documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: Thank you @Hector I added the html and a note for the value.

Comment: @ggorlen thank you for the note. I push the flipped[1] after I ask if(flipped.length == 1), there are now 2 elements in flipped, no? Alos, when I console.log(flipped[0] and [1]) right after the line: if(flipped[0].charAt(0) == flipped[1].charAt(0)) ,  I am able to see the values of the flipped cards in the console.

Comment: Still not entirely clear what you're doing or how you're going about it, as far as I can tell. There is no call to `flipcards` and (again, as far as I can tell) `card.getAttribute("src") == "back.png"` is always falsy (`card` seems to be `undefined`).

Comment: If you had issues using `getElementsByTagName()` did you try to access them by their index? e.g. this method will return an array of objects vs. a single object (even if there is only 1 match)